# Unity - Moving RigidBody to a point in a spherical world

Tags: unity, rigid-body-dynamics

I have a planet ( a spherical planet) that have units on the surface , that units are attracted by the planet  with this

```
  public void Attract(Transform body,Rigidbody rigidBody)
    {
        Vector3 gravityUp =  (body.position - transform.position).normalized;
        Vector3 bodyup = body.up;
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(bodyup, gravityUp) * body.rotation;

        body.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(body.rotation, targetRotation, 50*Time.deltaTime);
        rigidBody.AddForce(gravityUp*gravity);
    }
```

I want them to also move to a specific point in the planet but I can't make it work, I tryed lot of things, the most "near" to the solution was this code on the Update method, but his make unit to "bounce",

```
Vector3 dir = (positionToAchieve - transform.position).normalized * speed;
rigidBody.velocity = rigidBody.velocity + dir;
```

Any idea /suggestion will be welcome, I am new in Unity and I am learning it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this in your update instead:

```
public Transform target;
public float speed;
void Update() {
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
}
```

[Unity MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html)